# Java: How to uninstall self and exit

Tags: java, uninstallation

Is there a java utility that can be used by an application to uninstall itself and exit? I currently only use the executable jar to test this feature on a windows platform; there is no and there may never be a fancy installation mechanism other than providing the jar file(s).

```
File MYAPP = new File(".\\myapp.jar");
MYAPP.deleteOnExit();
System.exit(0);
```

only works (deletes myapp.jar) some of the time. In the Android environment all that is needed is:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.co.app");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);      
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

I was hoping the desktop environment had something similar.

Comment: This depends on how the program was installed, and in which environment (Windows/Linux/Mac). Please elaborate on that...

Comment: I am currently only using the development environment to debug. In the Android environment all that is needed is: `see edits to original question`

Comment: I think you should repost the question, but provide more detail :)

Comment: What I ended up doing is adding a function that writes, then runs a windows batch file that deletes all associated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you would have to write this yourself, but you could try something with [File.deleteOnExit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) but i'm not sure if that will work. it would depend on whether the JVM has unloaded the classpath before performing the deletes.

also have a look at installer packages, eg [NullsoftInstaller](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) which can be used to create installer/uninstaller software for your software.

Comment: I could only get deleteOnExit to work some of the time, I believe there may be a timing issue between unloading the classpath and the deletes. What I ended up actually doing is writing a function that writes, then runs a windows batch file with a short built in delay.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely not.

The uninstaller is usually created by the same process that created the installer, so I would look into that instead.